# can we use ' like or hate' with that

Tags: sentence-construction

I'm trying to figure out about what I want to say with the word 'like and hate'. For example, My friend lied to me last night. I hate that. When I translate this on Google, it becomes "I hate that my friend lied to me last night." As another example, my girlfriend always kisses me. I love that. When translating that, it said, "I love my girlfriend kissing me." Is google true? What can we say instead?

Comment: Google Translate is not always 100% smart about phrases and sentences. Is this your question: "Can I use 'I like that' or 'I hate that'"? Yes, as long as what you had just said makes it clear what "that" means, there's nothing wrong with ... that. :)

Comment: What do you mean by "translate this on google"  Which languages are you translating from and to?  You can't translate directly from English to English.

Comment: Thank you.Sir. I translated from my language to English

Answer (score 1):

When you want to love or hate an event you can use either *that* or *when*.
For example "I hate that my friend lied to me last night" has the same meaning as "I hated it when my friend lied to me last night". Note that when you use *when* you have to change the tense of *hate* to match when that event you hate actually happened and you need an extra *it*.

The example that Google gave you of "I love my girlfriend kissing me" sounds awkward. I would rephrase it as "I love it when my girlfriend kisses me" or "I loved it when my girlfriend kissed me" depending on whether you want to refer to the past or present tense. As a side note, the only time where *that* and *when* are not directly interchangeable is when you hate/love a fact/action/ability that doesn't just occur.

For example "I hate that you're better than me"≠"I hate it when you're better than me". Here, the first one implies that the other person is better than you ALL the time whereas the second just means the person is better than you SOME of the time. However the meanings are very similar and if your English isn't up to a point where you care about these pretty pedantic subtleties then you can use them interchangeably.

Comment: Sir, It's really very helpful explanation for me. Thank you so much.